# What is the cause of "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"-error with SQL INSERT statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

We use an application that has a not so user friendly way of managing its SQL Server database, which has led to quite some annoyance among colleagues. One of them therefore has asked me if I couldn't fabricate something in Excel with VBA that would make that part much easier. I could do that. And it works, except for one thing. Queries like this one:

```
INSERT INTO Bed (Description,FileName,TimeStamp,Status,Position,Active,Color,FontColor,Label,Ext,SiteId,DeviceId,PatientId,StudyId,TestStudyId,Deleted,AutoDischarge,KeepPatient,MobileStation) 
    VALUES ('Bed 6','C:\test','','','','1','','','','','1','3','4','19','','','','','')
```

result in this error:

*Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Bed' with unique index 'IX_Bed'. The duplicate key value is (0, 1).*

And I don't know why that is. Each bed has an automatically assigned BedId. I leave BedId out of the query (of course), so why is SQL Server accusing me of inserting a duplicate key value? When executing this query directly in SQL Server Management Studio the same error pops up, so Excel and VBA are not to blame.

Googling around on this error I only discovered topics mentioning it occurring with UPDATE statements, never with INSERT. So that didn't help me.

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: The reason is the same as an `UPDATE`; you are trying to `INSERT`/`UPDATE` a row which has identical values in columns in a unique index for another row in your table. So there is already a row with the value `0`, `1` in the columns defined in your index `IX_Bed`.

Comment: As an example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UZWx4qy0)

Comment: Each bed has an automatically assigned BedId - is bedid an identity or a regular INT with a default value (you want identity one :P)? you need to attach the create table script, easiest is to script table from management studio or run: exec sp_help 'Bed'

Comment: @ThomA Ah, yes... now I see. By scripting the IX_bed index I could see what columns were involved and indeed I inserted duplicate values there. Your fiddle also was very helpful. Thank you so much!